# Dotted line segments in pgfplots and changing font size in legend

Tags: pgfplots, fontsize

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={$x-t$ graph model of LAB 1},
    height=10cm,
    width=10.2cm,
    xlabel={time ($t$)},
    ylabel={position ($x$)},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
    legend pos=south east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend entries={$x$,$x^2$},
        legend style={
            at={(1.03,0.5)},
            anchor=west}
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,0)(1.48,2)(2.76,4)(4.02,6)(5.22,8)(6.43,10)(7.76,12)
    };
\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,0)(1.66,2)(3.21,4)(4.76,6)(6.32,8)(7.81,10)(9.47,12)
    };
\addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,12)(1.53,10)(2.94,8)(4.53,6)(5.95,4)(7.36,2)(8.83,0)
    };
\addplot[
    color=black,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,12)(1.80,10)(3.46,8)(4.94,6)(6.49,4)(8.20,2)(9.85,0)
    };
\legend{Trail 1 (fast and $+$), Trail 2 (slow and $+$), Trail 3 (fast and $-$), Trail 4 (slow and $-$)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following image:

[image: Graph]

I am wondering how I am make the above line segments dashed (ie the black, blue, red, green). I want to add a line of best fit over it, so I would like the lines to be dotted. Also, how do you change the text size of the legend? I would like it to be slightly smaller so I am make the graph larger. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made these changes:

1. added `every axis plot/.append style={line width=2pt,dotted}`, which makes each line 2pt wide in dotted style
2. added `mark options={solid}`, which makes the line for each mark solid, otherwise they would be dotted
3. added `font=\scriptsize`, to the `legend style`, to make the text of the legend smaller.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
compat=1.9,
every axis plot/.append style={line width=2pt,dotted} %<- added
}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={$x-t$ graph model of LAB 1},
    height=10cm,
    width=10.2cm,
    xlabel={time ($t$)},
    ylabel={position ($x$)},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
    mark options={solid},   %<- to get solid lines for markers
 %   legend pos=south east, %<- this is overwritten by legend style
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend entries={$x$,$x^2$},
        legend style={
            at={(1.03,0.5)},
            font=\scriptsize, %<- added
            anchor=west}
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,0)(1.48,2)(2.76,4)(4.02,6)(5.22,8)(6.43,10)(7.76,12)
    };
\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,0)(1.66,2)(3.21,4)(4.76,6)(6.32,8)(7.81,10)(9.47,12)
    };
\addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,12)(1.53,10)(2.94,8)(4.53,6)(5.95,4)(7.36,2)(8.83,0)
    };
\addplot[
    color=black,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,12)(1.80,10)(3.46,8)(4.94,6)(6.49,4)(8.20,2)(9.85,0)
    };
\legend{Trail 1 (fast and $+$), Trail 2 (slow and $+$), Trail 3 (fast and $-$), Trail 4 (slow and $-$)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This version applies the line style locally to each plot. This is done by adding `line width=2pt,dotted` to the options applied to each `\addplot`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %<- default
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
compat=1.9,
%every axis plot/.append style={line width=2pt,dotted} %<- added
}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={$x-t$ graph model of LAB 1},
    height=10cm,
    width=10.2cm,
    xlabel={time ($t$)},
    ylabel={position ($x$)},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
    mark options={solid},   %<- to get solid lines for markers
 %   legend pos=south east, %<- this is overwritten by legend style
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend entries={$x$,$x^2$},
        legend style={
            at={(1.03,0.5)},
            font=\scriptsize, %<- added
            anchor=west}
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    line width=2pt,
    dotted
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,0)(1.48,2)(2.76,4)(4.02,6)(5.22,8)(6.43,10)(7.76,12)
    };
\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    line width=2pt,
    dotted
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,0)(1.66,2)(3.21,4)(4.76,6)(6.32,8)(7.81,10)(9.47,12)
    };
\addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    line width=2pt,
    dotted
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,12)(1.53,10)(2.94,8)(4.53,6)(5.95,4)(7.36,2)(8.83,0)
    };
\addplot[
    color=black,
    mark=square,
    line width=2pt,
    dotted
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,12)(1.80,10)(3.46,8)(4.94,6)(6.49,4)(8.20,2)(9.85,0)
    };
\legend{Trail 1 (fast and $+$), Trail 2 (slow and $+$), Trail 3 (fast and $-$), Trail 4 (slow and $-$)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! However, I am presenting two graphs: one with the image that I already provided, and another like the one that you provided. I implemented your suggestion of using "every axis plot/.append style={line width=2pt,dotted}", but that overrode both of the graphs, while I only want that to be applied to the second graph. What should I do?

Comment: I added a second version that just applies the line style locally.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! However, I have one more small thing. How do you make the lines transparent? Like to a certain degree so that I can change values accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. For opacity, add `opacity=0.3` immediately after `dotted` in the options applied to the `\addplot` command.